# "No valid parser available" when calling SBT from python

Tags: python, scala, sbt

I am calling SBT from within a python script and need to access the runtime dependencies.

If I call the code below during step by step debugging then I get the desired result:

```
command = ["sbt", '"export runtime:dependencyClasspath"']
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If I run the same code without stopping at breakpoints however then I get the following:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /AAA/src/project
[info] Set current project to src (in build file:/AAA/src/)
[error] No valid parser available.
[error] "export runtime:dependencyClasspath"
[error]  ^
```

How can I get the runtime dependencies of a project in python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the extra quoting from your argument to `sbt`:

```py
# Don't nest quotes in the second argument.
command = ["sbt", "export runtime:dependencyClasspath"]
```